# can I have <br> linebreaks in title of an existing html table?

Tags: tabulator

(This is loading Tabulator from HTML)

I don't seem to be able to point the column definitions to existing titles if those titles contain a line break.

i.e. this `table>tr>th` will not work

```
<th >Primary<br/>Permission List?</th>
```

with

```
"columns": [
  {
    "title": "Primary<br/>Permission List?"
  },
  ...
```

Is there any way around this?  Aliases? I assume the `field` attribute doesn't help here.  Formatting differently in the columns options?  Can I modify the `<th>` HTML after the table is linked?

Not a huge deal if not possible, just checking.

Version:  tabulator-tables@5.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [titleFormatter](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/columns#definition) to display pretty much whatever you like in the title cell.

eg, in the column definition:

```
"columns": [
    ...,
    {
      title: "My<br>Multi<br>Line<br>Title",
      titleFormatter: (cell) => this.myTitleFormatter(cell),
      ...,
    }
```

and then the formatter function:

```
  private myTitleFormatter(cell) {
    const splitChars = "<br>";
    const cv = cell?.getValue() ?? "";
    const splits = cv.split(splitChars);
    if (splits.length > 1) {
      const el = document.createElement('span');      
      el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(splits[0]));
      splits.slice(1).forEach(s => {
        el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
      });
      return el;
    } else {
      return cv
    }
  }
```

The `<br>` is not actually HTML, just a marker/split point so you could use anything else like, say, '#$#':

```
 "My#$#Long#$#Title"
```

and use that for the `splitChars` in the formatter.